# Need to get a jsonrpc for a altcoin wallet but cant install a python module for python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitcoin

Hi I want to install a module on python 3.6 on Ubuntu I want to install this https://github.com/dpifke/pifkoin because you can you altcoins with it and i cant find a way to use altcoins only btc any help.

```
    python3 setup.py install
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 32, in <module>
    version=os.environ['VERSION'],
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
    KeyError: 'VERSION'
```

I need to connect to my altcoin wallet but don't how what jsonrpc I can use to connect with it or how.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

It's looking for an environment variable. A quick look through the source code suggests that this should work:

```
VERSION=0.1 python3 setup.py install
```

and there's also a Makefile:

```
make all
sudo dpkg -i deb_dist/python-pifkoin_$(VERSION)-1_all.deb
```

might also work.